# Change datatype of column SQLite3(Python)

Tags: database, python-2.7, sqlite, type-conversion

I have a database that I am reading with sqlite3 in Python 2.7, using the following command:

```
# Change to database directory
os.chdir(data)
# Find database file
cur_db = glob.glob('*.db')
# Connect to database
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = con.cursor()
# Query database
print(len(available_table))
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM col1 '):
        print row
```

which gives me something like:

`(1, u'2.3', u'brown', u'0', u'hairy', u'banana', u'2', u'monkey')`

I would like to look at values in the column w/ the value `u'2.3'` greater than `2`. But this is a unicode string instead of a number, making it difficult to compare to a number (eg `2`).

Ideally, I would like something like:

```
# Connect to database
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = con.cursor()
# Query database
c.execute('SELECT * FROM critter WHERE weight > 2'.
```

QUESTION: How can I add a conditional statement to extract only data rows where this element is greater than `2`? I would like to leave the database unaltered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: oh you want a query to do that... You can do:

```
for row in c.execute('select * from critter where cast(weight as numeric) > 2'):
  # do something
```

Older answer:
If you want to do this on the Python side you can use a try-except construct like so:

```
for row in c.execute('SELECT * FROM col1'):
  try:
    val = float(row[1]) # number here is the number of the element in the tuple
    if val > 2:
      print(val)
  except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: For the question I'd asked, your solution would probably work (I didn't try it). I edited the question to clarify what I am really asking (eg. not using a `for` loop to extract data from the table.

Comment: @AaronJPung: ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying. I edited my answer.

Comment: You are a god amongst men. Thank you, your solution works perfectly. I'd never heard/read of using `cast` in an execute call!